# How can i open in port 3306 in Ubuntu 8.04.1?

Tags: ubuntu, ufw

I want to open port using command `sudo ufw allow 3306/tcp` but it gives the following error:

```
sudo: ufw: command not found
```

please help me

Comment: retagged it, but newby questions are never false. May I hint you at Ubuntu community for questions like this?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Super User. Your question has been migrated here, where it is more adapted. To regain ownership over your question, you should create an account here, and associate it with your Stack Overflow account in user options.

Answer (score 4):

If the command ufw returns:

```
sudo: ufw: command not found
```

Than I'm almost sure that ufw is not installed yet.

Use apt-get to install ufw on you machine.
Like Matthew Flaschen typed above type:

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
```

Answer (score 1):

an open port helps you nothing, if you don't have a server listening on this port.

if you install mysql it will automatically open port 3306

Comment: Ihave to agree with knittle. 
At the moment it's sounding like you don't have ufw installed, so you may have misunderstood the purpose fo that line in the guide you're following?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
```

You'll find searching the web helpful on these types of questions.

Comment: Who needs to search the web when you can search the trilogy sites?

Answer (score 0):

Type `whereis ufw`. If you get back something like this:

```
ufw: /usr/sbin/ufw /usr/share/man/man1/ufw.1.gz ...
```

(I'm making up the details, I don't have ufw installed.) If you get back something like that, it tells you that the ufw binary is at /usr/sbin/ufw. Perhaps your $PATH doesn't recognize /usr/sbin. In that case you should call ufw with a full path: `sudo /usr/sbin/ufw allow 3306/tcp`.

ufw may well be somewhere inside /etc (or inside /etc/init.d), rather than in any .../bin directory.

If `whereis ufw` returns:

```
ufw:
```

then you probably don't have it installed, and will need to do:

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
```

as Matthew Flaschen says.